# Updating tooltip with changed value from onCellValueChanged() event handler

Tags: tooltip, ag-grid

I have set a 'tooltip' at columnDefs as below,

```
var columnDefs = [{
  headerName: "City",
  field: "city",
  cellRenderer: function(params) {
   return '<span title="'+params.value+'">'+params.value+'</span>';
  },
  editable: true
}
```

This tool tip is rendered properly on hover over the cells with the value in the cell.
Now I am also capturing the old and new values after a cell edit in onCellValueChanged() event handler as below,

```
onCellValueChanged: function(params) {
  if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
    // Send the values to the tool tip
  }
}
```

Is it possible to update my tool tip with the values captured in the onCellValueChanged() handler ? I mean, passing the params.oldValue and params.newValue() somehow to the 'tooltip' which is on my cellRenderer.

Comment: Based on the code the cellRenderer will always show the value in the span and as a title (tooltip). So if you have your data bind correctly, after edit the new values should be visible when hovering the cell, without implementing the onCellValueChanged method.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed, this [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1iCTFpJ4U5gVAN9r) updates tool tips when change occurs.

```
var oldValue = params.oldValue;
var newValue = params.newValue;

var recordKey = params.data.key;
var columnField = params.colDef.field;

if (!_.isEqual(oldValue, newValue)) {
  if (!cellMetadata[recordKey]) {
    cellMetadata[recordKey] = {};
  }
  if (!cellMetadata[recordKey][columnField]) {
   cellMetadata[recordKey][columnField] = {};
 }

cellMetadata[recordKey][columnField].trackChanges = true;
cellMetadata[recordKey][columnField].tooltip = 

  columnField.toUpperCase() + ' ' + 'Changed from' + ' ' + oldValue + ' ' + 'to' + ' ' + newValue;
  }
```